# How to extract json from a jsonp string in Scala

Tags: json, string, scala, parsing, jsonp

I am using Scala language and I have a response body like this:

```
_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(
  {
    response: {
      numFound: 1,
      start: 0,
      maxScore: 4.9338827,
      docs: [
        {
        tipo: "M",
        id: "mus1933196",
        s: 4.9338827,
        u: "daniellaalcarpe",
        d: "lagrima-de-amor",
        dd: "",
        f: "202114_20130510215437.jpg",
        a: "Daniella Alcarpe",
        t: "Lágrima De Amor",
        g: "MPB"
        }
      ]
    },
    highlighting: {
      mus1933196: {
        titulo: [
          "Lágrima <b>De</b> <b>Amor</b>"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
)
```

If I try to parse this as a json, it fails, because it is not actually a json. What is the best way to remove the `_SS_MainSolrCallbackH( )` part of the string, leaving only the json hash?

Comment: added update for regex

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach for an input `str: String` includes,

```
str.stripPrefix("_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(").stripSuffix(")")
```

which strips out the padding. For usability, consider for instance

```
def stripPadding(str: String, padding: String) =
  str.stripPrefix(padding+"(").stripSuffix(")")
```

**Update**

Using regular expressions, try

```
val re = """(?s)_SS_MainSolrCallbackH\((.*)\)""".r
re: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?s)_SS_MainSolrCallbackH\((.*)\)

scala> val re(x) = a
x: String =
"
  {
    response: {... } 
  }
"
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data type your response body is, and how robust you want to be against formatting changes (no line breaks, change of text "_SS_MainSolrCallbackH", extra lines around your posted text).

Assuming your response body is of type String, and the wrapping text around your body will always look as posted, it is as simple as removing the first and last line:

```
scala> val body = "_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(\n<some JSON>\n)"
body: String = 
_SS_MainSolrCallbackH(
<some JSON>
)

scala> val jsonStr = body.lines.toList.tail.init.mkString
jsonStr: String = <some JSON>
```

If you need a more sophisticated solution, please provide more details in your question.